# How to convert array into object?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have this array, `var arr = [0, 1, 2]`

and I would like to convert it into an object like this,

```
Object{
   data: [0, 1, 2]
}
```

How would I get the desired output using a function perhaps? Thanks.

Comment: `var obj = {data: arr};`

Comment: Why do you think you need to do this

Comment: These things are covered in JavaScript tutorials. Please read: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects and http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter4.html.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just create an object and assign the array to one it it's properties:

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2];
var obj = {
   data : arr
};
```

Or if you have an existing object, you can add the array by name:

```
obj['data'] = arr;
```

Or dot notation:

```
obj.data = arr;
```

You should be aware that these are all copying the array by reference, so any updates you make to the `arr` variable will update `obj.data` as well. If you want to copy by value, you could do something like:

```
var obj = {
    data: arr.slice(0)
};
```

See [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yh2qN/1) for an example of copying by reference versus copying by value. You could read the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6605640/javascript-by-reference-vs-by-value) for more information about copying by value vs copying by reference.

Comment: Your `copyByValue` function can basically be replaced by `arr.slice(0)`. It will create a shallow copy of the array as well.

Comment: @FelixKling Nice :) I didn't know that

Comment: @CHiRiLo Glad to have helped :) Since this answer helped you, would you mind accepting it so that other people who view the question will know it answers your question? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can do this very easily like this `var obj = {data:arr};` However I think you should consider what purpose you are using the object for. An array is technically already a javascript object so you may not even need to do this

Answer (score -1):

It's quite easy you just need a factory for it.

```
   function arrayToObjectTransformationFactory($array, $transformationTransportProtocol){
      return function($array){
        if ( !Array.prototype.forEach ) {
          Array.prototype.forEach = function(fn, scope) {
            for(var i = 0, len = this.length; i < len; ++i) {
              fn.call(scope, this[i], i, this);
            }
          };
        }
        $array.forEach($transformationTransportProtocol)
        return { "data": $array };
      }($array);
    }

    arrayToObjectTransformationFactory([0, 1, 2], function($element, $index, $array){
      var quux = [];
      quux.push($array[$index]);
    });
```

Should work cross browser and with jQuery too.

Comment: I don't quite understand this. What use is the function? You don't alter the array at all? Also it's all so complicated compared to a simple for loop since you would modify the array in place. I don't get it